# Showing irreducibility of $F(X)$ by looking at $F(1/X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, polynomials

I was reading Knapp's *Basic Algebra*, p. 455, and he is showing that the polynomial $F(X) = X^3 - X - \frac13 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is irreducible. To do so, he notes that $G(X):= -3X^3F(\frac1X) = X^3 - 3X^2 - 3$ is Eisenstein at $3$, and that any nontrivial factorization of $F$ would produce a nontrivial factorization of $G$.

I haven't seen this tactic before. Does it have a name?

Comment: The following link might be useful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088510/substituting-y-1-x-to-apply-eisensteins-criterion